# Explicit wait in protractor serenity

Tags: python, typescript, protractor

I am trying to create a base class to add the explicit weights in click and select methods. This is the code I have tried so far but I am getting the error on Click.on():

```
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { by } from "protractor";
import { protractor, browser } from 'protractor';

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;


export class wait{
    constructor() {
    }

    ElementVisibility(selector){
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath(selector));
    });
    }

    Click(selector) {
    this.ElementVisibility(selector).Click.on()
    }

}
```

Also when I import to another page is this the right way to do it? Sorry i am new to typescript and it is giving error and not recognizing the Click method

```
import { Task, step, PerformsTasks } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay";
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { CheckoutPageMap } from "../interactions/element-mappings/CheckoutPageMap";
import { wait } from "../interactions/element-mappings/wait";

export class FillPaymentMethod implements Task {
  static called(): FillPaymentMethod {
    return new FillPaymentMethod();
  }
  @step('{0} Select Shipping Method - Bruno selects for an item in men section')
  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
      Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.radioCreditCard),
      Enter.theValue('Bruno Sacco').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardHolderName),
      Enter.theValue('4032039926075500').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardNumber),
      Enter.theValue('123').into(CheckoutPageMap.textCreditCardCvv),
      wait.Click('//*[@id="card_month"]/option[.=" 09"]'),
      //Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.dropDownCreditCardMonth), // TO-DO: optimize choosing option from dropdown from properties file
      Click.on(CheckoutPageMap.dropDownCreditCardYear) // TO-DO: optimize choosing option from dropdown from properties file
    );
  }
};
```

getting this error - [ts] Property 'Click' does not exist on type 'typeof wait'.

Comment: because the `Click` method is not static, you should use instace of Wait class to call `Click` or declare it as static method by changing code to `static Click(selector) {}`, if you change `Click` to static, you have to change `ElementVisibility` to static also and remove `this.` inside `Click` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a code example, but I'm not sure your argument value for `locator` can compatible with `Protractor` locator.

```
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { protractor, element } from "protractor";

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

export class Wait{
    constructor() {
    }

    enterValue(text:any, locator:any) {
        //Enter.theValue comes from serenity
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(locator)), 5000)

        .then(function(){
            return Enter.theValue(text).into(locator);
        });

    }

    clickOn(locator: any): any {
        //Click.on comes from serenity
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(locator)), 5000)

        .then(function(){
            return Click.on(locator);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: also, it is giving me error on the enterValue - ts] Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'promise.Promise' from external module "/Users/chiragverma/Desktop/osxp-automation-master/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/index" but cannot be named.